# Results for python and MATLAB caffe are different for the same network

Tags: python, matlab, caffe, pycaffe, matcaffe

I am trying to port MATLAB implementation of [MTCNN_face_detection_alignment](https://github.com/kpzhang93/MTCNN_face_detection_alignment)
to python. I use the same version of caffe bindings for MATLAB and for python.

Minimal runnable code to reproduce the issue:

MATLAB:

```
addpath('f:/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/caffe/matlab');
warning off all
caffe.reset_all();
%caffe.set_mode_cpu();
caffe.set_mode_gpu();
caffe.set_device(0);
prototxt_dir = './model/det1.prototxt';
model_dir = './model/det1.caffemodel';
PNet=caffe.Net(prototxt_dir,model_dir,'test');
img=imread('F:/ImagesForTest/test1.jpg');
[hs ws c]=size(img)
im_data=(single(img)-127.5)*0.0078125;
PNet.blobs('data').reshape([hs ws 3 1]);
out=PNet.forward({im_data});
imshow(out{2}(:,:,2))
```

Python:

```
import numpy as np
import caffe
import cv2

caffe.set_mode_gpu()
caffe.set_device(0)

model = './model/det1.prototxt'
weights = './model/det1.caffemodel'

PNet = caffe.Net(model, weights, caffe.TEST) # create net and load weights

print ("\n\n----------------------------------------")
print ("------------- Network loaded -----------")
print ("----------------------------------------\n")

img = np.float32(cv2.imread( 'F:/ImagesForTest/test1.jpg' ))
img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

avg = np.array([127.5,127.5,127.5])
img = img - avg
img = img*0.0078125;
img = img.transpose((2,0,1)) 
img = img[None,:] # add singleton dimension

PNet.blobs['data'].reshape(1,3,img.shape[2],img.shape[3])
out = PNet.forward_all( data = img )

cv2.imshow('out',out['prob1'][0][1])
cv2.waitKey()
```

The model I use located [here](https://github.com/kpzhang93/MTCNN_face_detection_alignment/tree/master/code/codes/MTCNNv2/model) (det1.prototxt and det1.caffemodel)

The image I used to get these results:

[image]

The results I have from both cases:

[image]

Results are similar, but not same.

UPD: it looks like not type conversion problem (corrected, but nothing changed). 
I saved result of convolution after conv1 layer (first channel) in matlab, and extracted the same data in python, both images are now displayed by python cv2.imshow.

Data on input layer (data) are absolutely the same, I did the check using the same method.

And as you can see the difference visible even on the first (conv1) layer.
Looks like kernels transformed somehow.

[image]

Can anyone say where is the difference hidden ?

Comment: Just suggestions: 1) In MATLAB every `double` (the default type) gets converted to the type that is mixed with -- which in this case is `single`. Don't know about numpy -- is it the same? because you also mix precisions there. 2) Are you sure that the results are *numerically* different, or are just *displayed* differently by the two `imshow` functions?

Comment: @CST-Link: Mixing singles and doubles in numpy will result in a double.

Comment: @TheBlackCat Thank you for the specification.

Comment: Did you compare the input/output data layer by layer of the network in the 2 kinds of code? Maybe it can provide some clues.

Comment: Thanks, to all, for advices, I'll try to fix types convertions issue, and compare networks state layer by layer. BTW C++ implementation (pure cuDNN, no caffe) gives the same results as python, if it really not MATLAB imshow specifics. I'll check and will post results here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue source, it is because MATLAB sees image transposed.
This python code shows the same result as MATLAB one:

```
import numpy as np
import caffe
import cv2

caffe.set_mode_gpu()
caffe.set_device(0)

model = './model/det1.prototxt'
weights = './model/det1.caffemodel'

PNet = caffe.Net(model, weights, caffe.TEST) # create net and load weights

print ("\n\n----------------------------------------")
print ("------------- Network loaded -----------")
print ("----------------------------------------\n")

img = np.float32(cv2.imread( 'F:/ImagesForTest/test1.jpg' ))
img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img=cv2.transpose(img) # <----- THIS line !
avg = np.float32(np.array([127.5,127.5,127.5]))
img = img - avg
img = np.float32(img*0.0078125);
img = img.transpose((2,0,1)) 
img = img[None,:] # add singleton dimension

PNet.blobs['data'].reshape(1,3,img.shape[2],img.shape[3])
out = PNet.forward_all( data = img )

# transpose it back and show the result  
cv2.imshow('out',cv2.transpose(out['prob1'][0][1]))
cv2.waitKey()
```

Thanks all who advised me in comments !